# Finding mean from two different variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataset like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"type" :["A","B","C","A","B","B"], "value": [40,25,33,22,45,62]})
```

I want to find each individual type mean, ie., type = A has mean of 31
I did by subsetting

```
df_a = df.loc[df['type']=="A"]
df_a['value'].mean()
```

I want to do it in single line,
Thanks in advance

Comment: `df.gropuby('type')['value'].mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution might be:

```py
df.gropuby('type')['value'].mean()
```